# How to append buttons only for some users - socket.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I've made a basic chat program, where users can create rooms to chat. When creating a room, two buttons are appended to the list of rooms: a join button, and a remove button. 
However, for users who did not create the room, the 'remove button' should NOT be displayed, since they cannot remove the room. Only Owners (user who created the room) can remove a room.

Vice versa, for owners of a room, the 'join button' should NOT be displayed, since they don't have to join it.

Below you can see an image of what the chat program looks like. The buttons I am refering to are located on the left side.
[image]

---UPDATE with added code:
As you can see, when a client connects (server-side), the client's own id is emitted via the function "sendingOwnName".

On the client-side (in the beginning of the code) the id is then pushed into an array called "currentUser". Further down, in the "update-people" I compare currentUser with the id of a new user logging in.

The idea is that, if these two id's match, then the name of the object (new user logging in) is not added to the list. However it doesn't work.

client-side:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
        var socket = io.connect("localhost:3000");
        var $msg = $("#msg");
        var $NamingRoom = $("#NamingRoom");
        var $rooms = $("#rooms");
        var $chat = $('#chat');
        var $people = $('#people');
        var typing = false;  
        var timeout = undefined;
        var currentUser = [];
        $("#NewRoomWindow").hide();
        $("#main-chat-screen").hide();
        //Mere der skal gemmes
        $("#UsersOnlineAndRooms").hide();
        $("#msg").hide();
        $("#name").focus();
        $(".chatToInfo").hide();
        socket.on("sendingOwnName", function(id){
          currentUser.push(id);
        })


        $("form").submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
        });  
        
        $("#join").mousedown(function(){
            var name = $("#name").val();
            if (name.trim() != "") {
                socket.emit("join", name);
                $("#login").detach();
                $("#main-chat-screen").show();
                $("#UsersOnlineAndRooms").show();
                $rooms.show();
                $("#msg").show();
                $("#msg").focus();
                $("#rooms").show();
                $(".chatToInfo").show();
                ready = true;
               $("#msg").prop("readonly", true);
               $("#msg").attr("placeholder", "Start conversation or create/join room to chat");
               $("#send").attr("disabled", true);
            }
        }); 

        $("#name").keypress(function(e){
            if(e.which == 13) {
                var name = $("#name").val();
                if (name.trim() != "") {
                    socket.emit("join", name);
                    $("#login").detach();
                    $("#main-chat-screen").show();
                    $("#UsersOnlineAndRooms").show();
                    $rooms.show();
                    $("#msg").show();
                    $("#msg").focus();
                    $("#rooms").show();
                    $(".chatToInfo").show();
                    ready = true;
                   $("#msg").prop("readonly", true);
                   $("#msg").attr("placeholder", "Start conversation or create/join room to chat");
                   $("#send").attr("disabled", true);
                }
            }
        });  


        socket.on("update", function(newmsg) {
            if(ready)
                $chat.append("<div class='well well-sm'>" + msg + "</div>");
        }) 

        socket.on("updateToSelf", function(msg) {
                $("#chat").append('<div class="infoMessage">' + msg + "</div>");
              $('#chat').scrollTop($('#chat')[0].scrollHeight);
        }); 

        socket.on("updateToOthers", function(msg) {
                $("#chat").append('<div class="infoMessage">' + msg + "</div>");
              $('#chat').scrollTop($('#chat')[0].scrollHeight);
        }); 

        socket.on("update-peopleCount", function(data){
          $("#peopleCount").empty();
          $('#peopleCount').append("<li class=\"list-group-item active\">People online <span class=\"badge\">"+data.count+"</span></li>");
        });

        socket.on("update-people", function(data, id){
          $("#people").empty();
          $.each(data.people, function(a, obj, id) {
            //if (currentUser[0] === obj.id) {
            if (currentUser[0] == obj.id) {
              return;
            } else {
              $('#people').append("<li class=\"people-item\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"list-group-item\"><span class="+obj.id+">" + obj.name + "</span></a></li>");
            }
          });
        });


//Updating room list
        socket.on("roomList", function(data) {
          $("#rooms").text("");
          $("#rooms").append("<li class=\"list-group-item active\">List of rooms <span class=\"badge\">"+data.count+"</span></li>");

          if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(data.rooms)) { 
            $.each(data.rooms, function(id, room) {

            var html = "<button id="+id+" class='joinRoomBtn btn btn-default btn-xs' >Join</button>" + " " + "<button id="+id+" class='removeRoomBtn btn btn-default btn-xs'>Remove</button>" + " " + "<button id="+id+" class='leaveRoomBtn btn btn-default btn-xs'>Leave</button>";
            
            //var userButtons = "<button id="+id+" class='joinRoomBtn btn btn-default btn-xs' >Join</button>" + "" + "<button id="+id+" class='leaveRoomBtn btn btn-default btn-xs' >Leave</button>";
            //var ownerButton = "<button id="+id+" class='removeRoomBtn btn btn-default btn-xs'>Remove</button>";
            //var html = (room.owner === room.people? userButtons : ownerButton);
            $('#rooms').append("<li id="+id+" class=\"list-group-item\"><span>" + room.name + "</span> " + html + "</li>");
          });
          } else {
            $("#rooms").append("<li class=\"list-group-item\">There are no rooms available.</li>");
            $("#msg").prop("readonly", true);
            $("#msg").attr("placeholder", "Start conversation or create/join room to chat");
            $("#send").attr("disabled", true);
            }
        });

//Updating list of conversations
        socket.on("update-conversations", function(data) {
          $("#conversations").empty();
          $("#conversations").append("<li class=\"list-group-item active\">Conversations <span class=\"badge\">"+data.count+"</span></li>");

          if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(data.conversations)) {
            $.each(data.conversations, function(id, conversation) {
              var html = "<button id="+id+" class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'</button>";
              $('#conversations').append("<li id="+id+"><a href=\"#\" class=\"list-group-item\">" + conversation.name + "</a> " + html + "</li>");
            });
          } else {
              $("#conversations").append("<li class=\"list-group-item\">There are no conversations.</li>");
          }
        });



      
        socket.on("newMessageToOthers", function(people, msg){
            if(ready) {
                $("#chat").append('<div class="grey">'+ people + " says: " + msg + '</div>');
                $('#chat').scrollTop($('#chat')[0].scrollHeight);
            }
        });

     
       
        socket.on("ownMessage", function(msg){
            if(ready) {
                $("#chat").append('<div class="blue">' + msg + '</div>');
                $('#chat').scrollTop($('#chat')[0].scrollHeight);
            }
        });
    



        socket.on("disconnect", function(){
            $chat.append("The server is not available");
            $("#msg").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#send").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        });

// Sending the message (either by button click or enter) 
        $("#send").click(function(){
          var msg = $("#msg").val();
            if (msg.trim() == "") {
              return;
            } else {
                socket.emit("send message", msg);
                $("#msg").val("");
                $("#msg").focus();
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                  timeoutFunction();
            }
        });

        $("#msg").keypress(function(e){
          var msg = $("#msg").val();
          if (msg.trim() == "") {
              return;
            } else {
                if (e.which == 13) {
                  socket.emit("send message", msg);
                  $("#msg").val("");
                  $("#msg").focus();
                }
              }
          });



// Initiate new room window
        $("#roomModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
          $("#createRoomName").val("");
          $("#createRoomName").focus();
          $("#createRoomBtn").attr("disabled", true);
        })




// Creating new room
        $("#createRoomBtn").click(function(){
          var roomName = $("#createRoomName").val();
          if (roomName.trim() == "") {
            return;
          } else {
                $("#createRoomName").val("");
                socket.emit("serverCreateNewRoom", roomName);
                $("#msg").prop("readonly", false);
                $("#msg").attr("placeholder", "Your message");
                $("#send").attr("disabled", false);  
                $("#msg").focus();
                $("#roomModal").modal('hide');     
          }
        });

        $(".modal-content").keyup(function(e){
          var roomName = $("#createRoomName").val().trim();
          if (roomName!="") {
            $("#createRoomBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
            if (e.which == 13) {
                $("#createRoomName").val("");
                socket.emit("serverCreateNewRoom", roomName);
                $("#msg").prop("readonly", false);
                $("#msg").attr("placeholder", "Your message");
                $("#send").attr("disabled", false); 
                $("#msg").focus();
                $("#roomModal").modal('hide');
              }
          } else {
            $("#createRoomBtn").attr("disabled", "true");
          }
        });

// Joining room
        $("#rooms").on('click', '.joinRoomBtn', function(){
          var roomName = $(this).siblings("span").text();
          var roomID = $(this).attr("id");
          socket.emit("joinRoom", roomID);
          $("#msg").prop("readonly", false);
          $("#msg").attr("placeholder", "Your message");
          $("#send").attr("disabled", false); 
        });


//Starting conversation
        $("#people").on('click', '.list-group-item', function(){
          var peopleName = $(this).children("span").text();
          var peopleID = $(this).attr("id");
          //this har INTET id! Hvordan tilføjer jeg det til update-people, når user logger ind?
          socket.emit("serverCreateConversation", peopleName, peopleID); 
          $("#msg").prop("readonly", false);
          $("#msg").attr("placeholder", "Your message");
          $("#send").attr("disabled", false);  
          $("#chat").empty();    
        });

        socket.on("addConversation", function(peopleName) {
          $(".chatToInfo").empty();
          $(".chatToInfo").append('<div class="green">Message to ' + peopleName + '</div>');
        });  

        //Removing conversation
        $("#conversations").on('click', '.glyphicon', function(){
          var conversationName = $(this).siblings("a").text();
          var conversationID = $(this).attr("id");
          socket.emit("removeConversation", conversationID);
          $(".chatToInfo").empty();
          $("#chat").empty();  
          $("#msg").prop("readonly", true);
          $("#msg").attr("placeholder", "Start conversation or create/join room to chat");
          $("#send").attr("disabled", true);
        });

        //Navigating conversations
        $("#conversations").on('click', '.list-group-item', function(){
          console.log("clicking on conversation works!");
          var conversationName = $(this).text();
          var conversationID = $(this).attr("id");
          socket.emit("navigateToConversation", conversationName, conversationID);
          $("#msg").prop("readonly", false);
          $("#msg").attr("placeholder", "Your message");
          $("#send").attr("disabled", false); 
        });


// Removing room
        $("#rooms").on('click', '.removeRoomBtn', function(){
          var roomName = $(this).siblings("span").text();
          var roomID = $(this).attr("id");
          socket.emit("removeRoom", roomID);
        });

// Leaving room
        $("#rooms").on('click', '.leaveRoomBtn', function(){
          var roomName = $(this).siblings("span").text();
          var roomID = $(this).attr("id");
          socket.emit("leaveRoom", roomID);
          $("#msg").prop("readonly", true);
          $("#msg").attr("placeholder", "Start conversation or create/join room to chat");
          $("#send").attr("disabled", true);
        });




// Detect typing

          function timeoutFunction() {  
            typing = false;
            socket.emit("typing", false);
            socket.emit("notTyping", true)
          }

          $("#msg").keypress(function(e){
            if (e.which !== 13) {
              if (typing === false && $("#msg").is(":focus")) {
              typing = true;
              socket.emit("typing", true);
              clearTimeout(timeout);
              timeout = setTimeout(timeoutFunction, 3000);
              } 
            } else {
                  clearTimeout(timeout);
                  timeoutFunction();
                }
          });

          socket.on("isTyping", function(data) {  
            if (data.isTyping) {
              if ($("#"+data.person+"").length === 0) {
                $("#chat").append("<div id='"+ data.person +"'><span class='grey'>" + data.person + " is typing...</div>");
                timeout = setTimeout(timeoutFunction, 3000);
              }
            } else {
                //$("#chat").remove("<div id='"+ data.person +"'><span class='grey'>" + data.person + " is typing...</div>");
               $("#"+data.person+"").remove();
              }
          });


// Disconnect

          socket.on("disconnect", function(){
          $("#chat").append("<li class='well'><span class='text-warning'>The server is not available</span></li>"); 
          $("#msg").prop("readonly", true);
          $("#send").attr("disabled", true); 
          });

          socket.on("reconnect", function(){
            $("#chat").remove('.well'); 
            $("#msg").prop("readonly", false);
            $("#send").attr("disabled", false); 
          });


// End of script
      });
```

Server-side:

```js
// Setting up the server
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var socket = require("socket.io").listen(server);
var Room = require('./room.js');
var Conversation = require('./conversation.js');
var _ = require('underscore')._;
var uuid = require ('uuid');
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
console.log('Server is running...');

socket.set("log level", 1);
var people = {};  
var rooms = {};
var conversations = {};
var clients = [];
var chatHistory = {};

Array.prototype.contains = function(k, callback) {  
    var self = this;
    return (function check(i) {
        if (i >= self.length) {
            return callback(false);
        }
        if (self[i] === k) {
            return callback(true);
        }
        return process.nextTick(check.bind(null, i+1));
    }(0));
};



// Gets the html file
app.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})

// Gets the css file
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// When connecting
socket.on("connection", function(client) {
 client.on("join", function(name){
  var ownerRoomID = inRoomID = null;
  roomID = null;
  conversationID = null; // This line probably has to go, since users should be able to create several conversations.
  people[client.id] = {"name" : name, "owns" : ownerRoomID, "inroom" : inRoomID, "id" : client.id, "room" : roomID, "conversation" : conversationID};
  var id = uuid.v4();
  sizePeople = _.size(people);
  sizeRooms = _.size(rooms);
  sizeConversations = _.size(conversations);
  socket.sockets.emit("update-peopleCount", {people: people, count: sizePeople});
  socket.sockets.emit("update-people", {people: people});
  socket.sockets.emit("roomList", {rooms: rooms, count: sizeRooms});
  socket.sockets.emit("update-conversations", {conversations: conversations, count: sizeConversations});
  client.emit("updateToSelf", "You have connected to the server. Start conversation or create/join room to chat");
  client.broadcast.emit('updateToOthers', name + " is online.");
  clients.push(client); //populates the clients array with the client object
  console.log("Someone joined the chat", people[client.id].id);
  client.emit("sendingOwnName", people[client.id].id);
 });




//Creating room
 client.on("serverCreateNewRoom", function(name){
  console.log("About to create a room", name)
  if (people[client.id].inroom != null) {
   var id = uuid.v4();
   var room = new Room(name, id, client.id);
   rooms[id] = room;
   sizeRooms = _.size(rooms);
   socket.sockets.emit("roomList", {rooms: rooms, count: sizeRooms}); //update the list of rooms on the frontend
   client.room = name; //name the room
   client.join(client.room); //auto-join the creator to the room
   room.addPerson(client.id); //also add the person to the room object
   people[client.id].room = id; //Update the room key with the ID of the created room
   chatHistory[client.room] = [];  
   client.emit("updateToSelf", "You have left a room and created your own");
  }
  else if (people[client.id].room === null) {
   var id = uuid.v4();
   var room = new Room(name, id, client.id);
   rooms[id] = room;
   sizeRooms = _.size(rooms);
   socket.sockets.emit("roomList", {rooms: rooms, count: sizeRooms}); //update the list of rooms on the frontend
   client.room = name; //name the room
   client.join(client.room); //auto-join the creator to the room
   room.addPerson(client.id); //also add the person to the room object
   people[client.id].room = id; //Update the room key with the ID of the created room
   chatHistory[client.room] = [];  
   client.emit("updateToSelf", "You have created a room");
   console.log("First time creating a room", name);
   people[client.id].owns = id;
  } else {
   client.emit("updateToSelf", "You are already in a room, that you have created. Remove it to join a room");
  }
 });



//joining room
 client.on("joinRoom", function(id) {  
    var room = rooms[id];
    if (client.id === room.owner) {
      client.emit("updateToSelf", "You are the owner of this room and you have already been joined.");
    } else {
      room.people.contains(client.id, function(found) {
          if (found) {
              client.emit("updateToSelf", "You have already joined this room.");
          } else {
            if (people[client.id].inroom != null) { //make sure that one person joins one room at a time
             client.emit("updateToSelf", "You have to leave this room before you can join another");
             console.log("User is already in a room");
            } else {
          var id = uuid.v4();
          room.addPerson(client.id);
          people[client.id].inroom = id;
          client.room = room.name;
          client.join(client.room); //add person to the room
          user = people[client.id];
          client.broadcast.to(client.room).emit("updateToOthers", user.name + " has connected to " + room.name);
          client.emit("updateToSelf", "Welcome to " + room.name + ".");
          client.emit("sendRoomID", {id: id});
          console.log("User joined a room" + room.name);
        }
          }
      });
    }
  });




// When sending
 client.on("send message", function(msg){ 
  if (_.size(chatHistory[client.room]) > 10) {
   chatHistory[client.room].splice(0,1);
  } else {
   chatHistory[client.room].push(people[client.id].name + ": " + msg)
  }
   client.broadcast.to(client.room).emit("newMessageToOthers", people[client.id].name, msg);
   client.emit("ownMessage", msg);
   console.log(chatHistory);
  console.log("Message send");
 });


//When leaving room
 client.on("leaveRoom", function(id){
  console.log("Someone is trying to leave room");
  var room = rooms[id];
  if (client.id === room.owner) {
   console.log("Owner is leaving the room");
   var i = 0;
   while(i < client.length) {
    if (client[i].id == room.people[i]) {
     people[clients[i].id].inroom = null;
     clients[i].leave(room.name);
    }
    ++i;
   }
   delete rooms[id];
   people[room.owner].owns = null; //reset the owns object to null so new room can be added
   socket.sockets.emit("roomList", {rooms: rooms});
   delete chatHistory[room.name];
   client.broadcast.in(client.room).emit("updateToOthers", "The owner (" + people[client.id].name + ") is leaving the room. The room is removed.");
   client.emit("updateToSelf", "You left your room");
   people[client.id].room = null;
   sizeRooms = _.size(rooms);
       socket.sockets.emit("roomList", {rooms: rooms, count: sizeRooms});
  } else {
   room.people.contains(client.id, function(found){ 
    if (found) { //make sure that the client is in fact part of this room
     var personIndex = room.people.indexOf(client.id);
     room.people.splice(personIndex, 1);
     client.leave(client.room);
     people[client.id].inroom = null
     client.emit("updateToSelf", "You left the room");
     console.log("Left the room");
    }
   });
  }
 });

//when removing a room (only the owner of the room can remove it)
 client.on("removeRoom", function(id){
  var room = rooms[id];
  if (room) {
   if (client.id === room.owner) { //only the owner can remove the room
    var personCount = room.people.length;
    if (personCount > 2) {
     console.log('there are still people in the room warning'); //This will be handled later
    } else {
     if (client.id === room.owner) {
      delete chatHistory[room.name];
      client.emit("updateToSelf", "You removed the room.");
      client.broadcast.to(client.room).emit("updateToOthers", "The owner (" +people[client.id].name + ") removed the room.");
      var i = 0;
      while(i < clients.length) {
       if (clients[i].id === room.people[i]) {
        people[clients[i].id].inroom = null;
        clients[i].leave(room.name);
       }
       ++i;
      }
       delete rooms[id];
       people[client.id].room = null;
       sizeRooms = _.size(rooms);
       socket.sockets.emit("roomList", {rooms: rooms, count: sizeRooms});
     }
    }
   } else {
    console.log("Someone who is NOT the owner is trying to remove a room");
    client.emit("updateToSelf", "Only the owner can remove a room.");
   }
  }
 });




// Creating conversation
 client.on("serverCreateConversation", function(name) {
  // Missing a if-statement that makes sure a conversation with the same person isn't already open
  console.log("About to create conversation");
  var id = uuid.v4();
  var conversation = new Conversation(name, id, client.id);
  conversations[id] = conversation;
  sizeConversations = _.size(conversations);
  socket.sockets.emit("update-conversations", {conversations: conversations, count: sizeConversations});
  client.conversation = name;
  client.join(client.conversation);
  conversation.addPerson(client.id);
  people[client.id].conversation = id;
  console.log("Created conversation");
  client.emit("addConversation", name);
 });

 client.on("removeConversation", function(id){
  console.log("About to remove conversation");
  var conversation = conversations[id];
  //if (conversation) {
   console.log("Removing conversation function");
   delete conversations[id];
   people[client.id].conversation = null;
   sizeConversations = _.size(conversations);
   socket.sockets.emit("update-conversations", {conversations: conversations, count: sizeConversations});
  //}
 });
 
 //Navigating conversations
 client.on("navigateToConversation", function(name){
  console.log("caught navigation");
  client.emit("addConversation", name);
 });



// Detect typing

 client.on("typing", function(data) {  
    if (typeof people[client.id] !== "undefined")
     //socket.sockets.in(client.room).emit("isTyping", {isTyping: data, person: people[client.id].name});
     client.to(client.room).emit("isTyping", {isTyping: data, person: people[client.id].name});
     console.log("Someone is typing");
 });


// When disconnecting
 client.on("disconnect", function(id) { 
  console.log("someone disconnected");
  var room = rooms[id];
  if (people[client.id]) {
   if (people[client.id].owns != null) { //Check if user is an owner of a room
    var room = rooms[people[client.id].owns];
    var i = 0;
    while(i < clients.length) {
     if (clients[i].id === room.people[i]) {
      people[clients[i].id].inroom = null;
      clients[i].leave(room.name);
     }
       i++;
    }
    delete rooms[people[client.id].owns];
    socket.sockets.emit("updateToOthers", "The owner (" + people[client.id].name + ") is leaving the room. The room is removed.");
    delete rooms[id];
    delete people[client.id];
    sizePeople = _.size(people);
    socket.sockets.emit("update-peopleCount", {people: people, count: sizePeople});
    socket.sockets.emit("update-people", {people: people});
    sizeRooms = _.size(rooms);
    socket.sockets.emit("roomList", {rooms: rooms, count: sizeRooms});
   }
   else if (people[client.id].inroom != null ) { //Check if user who is not owner is in room 
    console.log(people[client.id].name);
    socket.sockets.emit("updateToOthers", people[client.id].name + " has left the room.");
    delete people[client.id];
    sizePeople = _.size(people);
    socket.sockets.emit("update-peopleCount", {people: people, count: sizePeople});
    socket.sockets.emit("update-people", {people: people});
   }
   else { //A user who is not in a room
    console.log(people[client.id].name);
    socket.sockets.emit("updateToOthers", people[client.id].name + " has left the server.");
    delete people[client.id];
    sizePeople = _.size(people);
    socket.sockets.emit("update-peopleCount", {people: people, count: sizePeople});
    socket.sockets.emit("update-people", {people: people});
   }
  }
  });

 client.on("test", function(currentUser){
  console.log("testing", currentUser);
 });

 


// End of script
});
```

Comment: Sorry, i badly read your question, i edited my answer for what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your object `rooms` look like this:

```
{
  "RoomId1": {
    "name": "A Room Name"
    },
  "RoomId2": {
    "name": "An Other Room"
    }
}
```

Maybe you could just add the owner id on the object to get something like this:

```
{
  "RoomId1": {
    "name": "A Room Name",
    "ownerId": "user1"
    },
  "RoomId2": {
    "name": "An Other Room",
    "ownerId": "user2"
    }
}
```

and then compare it with the current user of the chat:

```
//replace this line:
var html = "<button id="+id+" class='joinRoomBtn btn btn-default btn-xs' >Join</button>" + " " + "<button id="+id+" class='removeRoomBtn btn btn-default btn-xs'>Remove</button>";
//with those:
var joinButton = "<button id="+id+" class='joinRoomBtn btn btn-default btn-xs' >Join</button>";
var removeButton = "<button id="+id+" class='removeRoomBtn btn btn-default btn-xs'>Remove</button>"
//Here the userId must be define before, i don't know how you can get it.
var html = (room.ownerId === userId?" removeButton : joinButton);
```

i use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to get all in one line, but you could use an if statement. You could replace the last part of the operator by `""` if you don't want to show it.

#### Update:

At the end your code should look like this:

```
//Updating room list
socket.on("roomList", function(data) {
  $("#rooms").text("");
  $("#rooms").append("<li class=\"list-group-item active\">List of rooms <span class=\"badge\">"+data.count+"</span></li>");

  if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(data.rooms)) { 
    $.each(data.rooms, function(id, room) {
      var joinButton = "<button id="+id+" class='joinRoomBtn btn btn-default btn-xs' >Join</button>";
      var removeButton = "<button id="+id+" class='removeRoomBtn btn btn-default btn-xs'>Remove</button>";
      var html = (room.ownerId === userId?" removeButton : joinButton);
      $('#rooms').append("<li id="+id+" class=\"list-group-item\"><span>" + room.name + "</span> " + html + "</li>");
    });
  } else {
    $("#rooms").append("<li class=\"list-group-item\">There are no rooms.</li>");
    $("#msg").prop("readonly", true);
    $("#msg").attr("placeholder", "Join or create room to chat");
    $("#send").attr("disabled", true);
  }
});
```

Comment: I have tried this code, but now the room and the buttons do not even appear on the list of rooms. It says 'ownerId is not defined. How do I define it?': var joinButton = "<button id="+id+" class='joinRoomBtn btn btn-default btn-xs' >Join</button>";
            var removeButton = "<button id="+id+" class='removeRoomBtn btn btn-default btn-xs'>Remove</button>";
            var html = (room.ownerId === ownerId?"removeButton" : "joinButton");

Comment: I have updated my question with code that shows how a new room (and ownership of it) is being created. Can I use that to to define the ownerId in your code?

Comment: i made a (other) mistake, the test must compare the `ownerId` (the id of the user that create the room) and the current `userId`. In your class `Room` you must have an attribute for the owner of the room.

Comment: If the id of the user matches the userId, will the buttons not append to all sockets?

Comment: It should not. `each` is an iterator, and take 2 arguments: an object and a callback. For each element inside your object (here it's `rooms`), he will call the callback one time. The callback will receive the key and the value as parameters. On your code, you append to the element with the identifier `rooms`, a new element  `li` for each room.

Comment: I tried your code, and it works for the owner of the room. However, other users who log in see the same button (remove), but they should be able to see 'join' and 'leave', not 'remove'. I guess I need to edit the server.js to achieve this. Do you agree? I'm a bit lost here

Comment: How do you get the Id of the current user on the client side ? Can you develop the data you send from the server pls ?

Comment: I've added code both from client,- and server-side. Hope it gives you a complete understanding of what is going on in my code. I really appreciate that you are using your time to help me with this!

Comment: No problems =)! What is the `room.people` attribute. On the client you should have a variable for the id of the current `User` and use it. For example you could send from the server, the data of the user when he connect and use it instead of room.people on client side. I hope this will help you!

Comment: Am I correct to assume that I can send the data like this: client.emit(people) ? 'people' stores all the objects (users).

Comment: It's almost that: look at the documentation of [socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-emit-eventname-args-ack). `socket` take two arguments, a string: the name of the event and an object the thing you want to send. that's on server side. On client side you must handle this event. Use [socket.on method](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket-on-eventname-callback) with the same event name.